# Which SQL table structure is better for storing data by months?

Tags: mysql, sql

I will be storing data into a database table by months, and I'm wondering which table structure is best out of the following.

For what it's worth, I will be using MySQL and would prefer to use option 1.

**option 1** - (I think this is normalization)

```
month_id - tinyint unsigned
value - int unsigned
```

**option 2** - storing 1 month per table field

```
january - int unsigned
february - int unsigned
march - int unsigned
(etc to December.)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the difference is between the two, can you clarify?  Also, what are you intending to use this for?  It seems almost easier, since the values are well known and never change, to just store the month number without having a lookup table.

Comment: Both options use 1 table. Option 1 uses 2 fields. Option 2 uses 12 fields.

Comment: Ah, I see - if you intend to use a lookup table, use the first option.

Comment: How you store data should be based on how you use the data (both how it is inserted and the queries).  The first version is more normalized and that is often a good thing.  Often, though, tables that summarize reports are in the second format.

Comment: Okay thanks, and yeh the data will be for reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1.

It's easy to extend if you ever need more than one year.

Then if you need the data in the other format you can use:

```
Select 
  sum(case month_id when 1 then Value end) as January,
  sum(case month_id when 2 then Value end) as February,
  sum(case month_id when 3 then Value end) as March,
  sum(case month_id when 4 then Value end) as April,
  sum(case month_id when 5 then Value end) as May,
  sum(case month_id when 6 then Value end) as June,
  sum(case month_id when 7 then Value end) as July,
  sum(case month_id when 8 then Value end) as August,
  sum(case month_id when 9 then Value end) as September,
  sum(case month_id when 10 then Value end) as October,
  sum(case month_id when 11 then Value end) as November,
  sum(case month_id when 12 then Value end) as December
from MonthlyData
```